# How do I sign click once applications?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, clickonce

I have written an application, that I'm publishing to my webpage everytime I make changes via the "Publishing Assistant" in VS13. If I'm going to install it on my PC from my website Windows tells me that the application would not be trustful. How do I change this? Where do I get an certificate for signing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You buy a certificate from any trusted certificate provider. To not to promote any specific provider, I'll just recommend you to google for "buy code signing certificate", if you really can't find a provider on your own.

Then, at the properties tabs, navigate to the "Signing" tab and point to your certificate file. The package will be signed upon building.